# window.screen in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, screen

guys. I have the following problem:

I detect sreen width and height via window.screen object.
But in firefox, when I scale my browser, I got different values of this parameters.

**Example:**

**100% scale:**
Screen { availWidth: 2556, availHeight: 1417, width: 2560, height: 1440, colorDepth: 24, pixelDepth: 24, top: 0, left: 0, availTop: 23, availLeft: 4 }

**110% scale:**
Screen { availWidth: 2343, availHeight: 1299, width: 2347, height: 1320, colorDepth: 24, pixelDepth: 24, top: 0, left: 0, availTop: 21, availLeft: 4 }

etc...

How can I get an actual screen width and height?

Any help will be appreciated. =)

Answer (score 0):

it's 100% .
calculations are in pixels and whenever u zoom +/- , pixel=pixel*multiplier is done;

example : (2343*110)/100 = actual pixels, because when u zoom pixels were joined, not literally to create a ratio of 1.1:1 ie.e 11 pixels were treated as ten.

less pixels on huge monitor = zoom up.

it treat 1, 1.25 or whatsoever as a single pixel depending on multiplier.
and this multiplier is controlled through zoom in and zoom out UI.

try to let it as it is, if u are using values in element customization.

Comment: 'alculations are in pixels and whenever u zoom +/- , pixel=pixel*multiplier is done;'

But only in firefox this values are changing.

Answer (score 0):

when screen resolution scale is 100%. at that time you can get actual width and height. once you scale up the browser by 10% or more that means you re-size your window so you'll get the different value.

actual value will be for scale 100%. :)